# Is it possible to change proxy without restarting Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, proxy

I am trying to scrape a website that renders all the date with JS. It pages of tables, however you can only access certain page via search box or by clicking an arrow to move to next page. It is impossible to access certain page by url.

I need to change proxy on each page. If I reload webdriver, I must execute all the searches to access e.g. 124102nd page. It is very time as well as computationally intensive.

Anyone could help me on this?